# CSS3 submenu's submenu dont work correctly

Tags: css

i have created a css3 style sheet for creating menu, in submenu of main menu is correct but after creating submenu. The child element of the submenu does not work correctly.

i want to move submenu's submenu to bottom of parent and i can move mouse cursor on child

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/frz7q/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav" style='margin-right:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;height:30px;'>
    <li><a>MAIN MENU</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab1">MENU 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>SUBMENU</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">MENU 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">MENU 3</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS3:**

```
#nav {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    height: 33px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #5E9AE2, #3570B8) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    z-index: 10000;
}
#nav li {
    margin: 0pt 5px;
    padding: 2pt 0pt 5px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none outside none;
    z-index: 10000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nav a {
    color: #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-right: 0pt;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-weight: normal;
    z-index: 100000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nav .current a, #nav li:hover > a {
    z-index: 100000;
    background: #fff ! important;
    color: #000 ! important;
    box-shadow: 0pt 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#nav ul li:hover a, #nav li:hover li a {
    z-index: 100000;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    color: #000 ! important;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(198, 71, 53), rgb(147, 35, 19)) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent ! important;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c44634), color-stop(100%,#952414)) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent ! important; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #c44634 0%,#952414 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent ! important; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #c44634 0%,#952414 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent ! important; /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #c44634 0%,#952414 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent ! important; /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #c44634 0%,#952414 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent ! important; /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c44634', endColorstr='#952414',GradientType=0 ) ! important; /* IE6-9 */
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) ! important;
    border-radius: 0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;
    text-shadow: 0pt 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nav ul {
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #cfcfcf 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#cfcfcf)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#cfcfcf 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#cfcfcf 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#cfcfcf 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#cfcfcf 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#cfcfcf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    display: none;
    margin: 0pt;
    padding: 0pt;
    text-align: right;
    width: 180px;/*طول منو*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    right: 0pt;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    direction: rtl;
    box-shadow: 0pt 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0pt;
    padding: 0pt;
}
#nav ul li ul{
    float: none;
    margin-top:28px;
    margin-right: 180px;
    top: 0px;
}
#nav ul li ul li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;

    behavior: url('./css/PIE.htc');
}
#nav ul li ul li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    behavior: url('./css/PIE.htc');
}

#nav ul a {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 0pt 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.898);
}
#nav ul li:first-child > a {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    behavior: url('./css/PIE.htc');
}
#nav ul li:last-child > a {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    behavior: url('./css/PIE.htc');
}
#nav:after {
    z-index: 100000;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0pt;
    height: 0pt;
}
```

this method not problem but i want to have any submenu and cant fix it.please help me,

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your situation ? I am unable to figure out what your 'bug'/wish is.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav ul li ul {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 180px;
    margin-top: 28px; /* <-- this is causing issue */
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know where the problem every thing work just remove margin-top
and add the html

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav" style='margin-right:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;height:30px;'>
<li><a>MAIN MENU</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">MENU 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>SUBMENU</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>asdasd</a></li>
                        <li><a>asdasd</a></li>
                        <li><a>asdasd</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">MENU 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">MENU 3</a></li>
    </ul>       
</li>
```

see demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/frz7q/1/)

Comment: thanks, but i want to move submenu's submenu to bottom of parent

Comment: after insert this line, i cant move mouse cursor on submenu's submenu

Comment: that's it if you apply the margin you found difficult in navigate